# Having trouble accessing my textbox input in a class

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB and am having a little trouble with my class assignment. Basically it is supposed to take an invoice subtotal - find the discount percent and give the real total. I cant seem to get my class to access the textbox for user input and it just keeps returning 0's. This is a homework assignment as well... im not asking for the answer just some tips because i am truly at a loss and cannot figure this out!!!

This is my code from the button click event:

```
Public Sub btnCalc_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
    'If txbxSubtotal.Text >= 500 Then
    '   discountpercent = 0.2
    'ElseIf txbxSubtotal.Text >= 250 And txbxSubtotal.Text < 500 Then
    '   discountpercent = 0.15
    'ElseIf txbxSubtotal.Text >= 100 And txbxSubtotal.Text < 250 Then
    '   discountpercent = 0.1
    'Else
    '   discountpercent = 0
    'End If
    'discountAmount = txbxSubtotal.Text * discountpercent
    'total = txbxSubtotal.Text - discountAmount
    Dim myinvoice As New Getinvoice
    myinvoice.setAmount(total = Convert.ToDecimal(txbxSubtotal.Text))
    total = txbxSubtotal.Text
    MessageBox.Show(myinvoice.getdiscountAmount)
    MessageBox.Show(myinvoice.getAmount)
End Sub
End Class
```

and this is the code inside my class:

```
Public Class Getinvoice

    Private subtotal As Decimal
    Private discount As Decimal
    Private discountAmount As Decimal
    Private discountpercent As Decimal
    Private amount As Decimal

    Public Sub setAmount(ByVal total As Decimal)
        amount = total
    End Sub

    Public Function getAmount()
        Return amount
    End Function

    Public Sub setdiscountPercent(ByVal discPcnt As Decimal)
        discountAmount = discPcnt

        If amount >= 500 Then
            discountpercent = 0.2
        ElseIf amount >= 250 And amount < 500 Then
            discountpercent = 0.15
        ElseIf amount >= 100 And amount < 250 Then
            discountpercent = 0.1
        Else
            discountpercent = 0
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function getdiscountAmount()
        Return discountpercent
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You have never called

```
setdiscountPercent(ByVal discPcnt As Decimal)
```

So the discountpercent is never set. That is why you get 0;

EDIT:

```
Public Sub setdiscountPercent(ByVal discPcnt As Decimal)
    discountAmount = discPcnt

    If amount >= 500 Then
        discountpercent = 0.2
    ElseIf amount >= 250 And amount < 500 Then
        discountpercent = 0.15
    ElseIf amount >= 100 And amount < 250 Then
        discountpercent = 0.1
    Else
        discountpercent = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

This is your code. Take a look you set inside this method `discountAmount = discPcnt`

But when in the code you have posted you never call `setdiscountPercent(ByVal discPcnt As Decimal)`

So discountAmount  and discountpercent are never set to any value. And this is where you problem come from.

Comment: The discountpercent depends on the amount of the subtotal thoughI am really confused though, because even when i do a msgbox to check and see if the user input for the subtotal (from txbxsubtotal.text) I will enter 5000 and that too returns 0

Comment: You have to call setdiscountPercent(ByVal discPcnt As Decimal) atleast once so you can have some value stored inside "discountpercent" and "discountAmount"

Comment: Even when i dont run the program to try and get the discountpercent and just the amount(subtotal) that the user enters through the txbxsubtotal.text It returns a value of 0 even if I enter 5000.. so i think the problem is that the textbox input is not passing through into the class?